# Can "ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64" be installed on a work station with Intel Xeon CPU?

Tags: server, 64-bit

everyone!I want to install 64-bit ubuntu on our work station, but the downloaded iso file have an extension of "AMD64", and our work station has a CPU of "intel Xeon(E5540 2.53GHz*4)". Can I install the downloaded "ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64" on our work station?
Any answer would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't see why not. AMD64 is part of the name, and is a convention, rather then extension.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://ark.intel.com/products/37104/, your workstation is 64-bit, and AMD64 refers to the file being for a 64-bit machine. So, most likely your installation will work. If there are problems with the installation, it won't be because of "AMD64".

The extension of your file should be .iso if you are burning it to a disc or USB drive.

Comment: Just as your prediction, I have installed 64-bit ubuntu on our work station. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept my answer to mark your question as answered.